# routes not calling the function in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When i go with routes in my browser,it shows the results in my console but in network the server call is running for long time ,can someone suggest help/.............

My controller,

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var mysql     =    require('mysql');
 var connection      =    mysql.createConnection({
 // connectionLimit : 100, //important
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'root',
 password : 'root',
 database : 'socialwiki'
 });
connection.connect(function(error){
if(!!error){
 console.log('error');

}else{
  console.log('connected');
 }
});
exports.getlist = function( req, res ) {
connection.query("SELECT * FROM     profile",function(error,result,rows,fields){
if(!!error){
    console.log('fail');
}else{
  console.log(result);
}
```

});
  }

I am trying to provide routes at my routes folder,
user.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var app = express();
 var admin = require('../controller/user'); 
 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/hm', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  });
 router.get('/hm1', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Entertainment' });
 });
 router.get('/users', admin.getlist)
 module.exports = router;
```

I am completely new to express js can someone suggest help please.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the HTTP response, using `res.send` in express

For example:

```
exports.getlist = function(req, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM     profile", function(error, result, rows, fields) {
    if (!!error) {
      console.log('fail');
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
};
```

The only change was to add [`res.send(result)`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) as the last thing your script does.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filype,can you suggest some best documents for me

Comment: Here i want to get all the list except one record has id =1 and how can i do that

Comment: i mean get call with id as parameter